# Prevent textarea from resetting after going to another page and coming back

Tags: php, html, textarea

The default behavior of a textarea in a page when the user clicks in a link inside the page and then clicks the "back" button is to reset it's content. How can i prevent this?

Right now i have a PHP page with a textarea. The PHP script generates a small content and puts into the textarea, but if the user clicks in a link and then clicks the back button, the text doesn't appear anymore in the textarea.

ps.: Without using session, please.

What i'm actually doing:

page.php

```
<textarea readonly="readonly"><?php echo $somevarhere ?></textarea>
<a href="nicelink.php">Hey</a>
```

So, when i open page.php and click "Hey", i go to nicelink.php. If i press the back button, however, the content of the textarea is gone. I have to press F5 for the PHP to generate the page once again, and therefore the textarea content. How to prevent the textarea from being reset?

Comment: Can the downvoter at least give a reason for the downvote?

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) for an HTML5 solution

Comment: Any solution other than localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you don't want the visitor to change the TextArea. Maybe try setting it to read only?

Comment: That's not exactly the question. The textarea is already readonly and it's contents are generated from my PHP script. I just don't want it to be reset when the user leaves the page and comes back.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the content of $somevarhere into a javascript variable and load it via ajax when $somevarhere is empty, transmit it via json etc. when loading the page or via event handlers.

Thats complicated but without sessions that should work...